# how to view content of str contains bool array?

Tags: python, pandas

Due to large number of columns I was trying to search for column names where the column name has 'el' in it. This is the code I tried

```
combined.columns.str.contains("el")
```

But the result I'm getting is a Boolean array how can I view the column names that returned true from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `:` for select all rows:

```
combined.loc[:, combined.columns.str.contains("el")]
```

Or use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
combined.filter(like='el')
```

Comment: I get a ValueError: Item wrong length 160 instead of 363

Comment: @sai_636 - oops, I forget for `loc` and `:`

Comment: Now it works! Thanks